# Enclosing ExecuteReader in Try/Catch makes it succeed?

Tags: c#, windows, service, sqlcommand

My project wrote a small Windows service in c# to start a couple of processes on our servers.
Our new service is made dependent on MSSQLSERVER service and starts/runs/stops reliably when operated from within a user session.

At boot time though, our limited-performance hardware is very busy and it appears that though MSSQLSERVER has reported back to the Service Control Manager as 'started', it isn't quite ready to service queries.  So although, when we open our SQLConnection it succeeds, the first attempt to query "sometimes" (about 50/50) fails.

My (admittedly blunt) approach to addressing this has been to take the ExecuteReader method I believe is failing:

```
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

and place it in a Try/Catch with a 1s delay and let it retry up to 10 times:

```
        bool bReady = false;
        int iErrCount = 0;
        while (bReady == false && iErrCount < 10)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                bReady = true;
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Starting...",EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
            catch
            {
                bReady = false;
                iErrCount += 1;
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Failed once...",EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            }
        }

        if (bReady == false)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Failed ten times.  Service will now exit.",EventLogEntryType.Error);
            return; 
        }
```

My quandry is, although this approach is working perfectly and allows the service to start every time, if I check the event log, it actually always succeeds on the first try!  The exception I'm trying to catch now never occurs.
It's as though something about placing the method call inside the Try/Catch itself has affected it's likelihood of succeeding.

Any thoughts most welcome.

Comment: How about finding out what the problem is, then solving it? How about `try {executeReader();}catch(Exception ex){EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());}`?

Comment: When it "fails", what exception do you get?

Comment: Just guessing, but the reason can be performance optimization of .NET See here: [http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/06/22/performance-implications-of-try-catch-finally.aspx](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/06/22/performance-implications-of-try-catch-finally.aspx)

Comment: Thanks all.  Some interesting things to look at.

Comment: It takes a little while to get a build into our test environment, but I'll update as I get closer to the problem.  John: my problem is I never get an Exception caught when I try/catch.  Eren: when it fails it's a SQLException concerning a db still being Recovered (this is semi-expected !?!), Ondra: thanks, really interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you didn't add a Thread.Sleep that wasn't there before?

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

If that wasn't there before, now you're sleeping for a second before trying to open the connection. Maybe that's all you needed.

Comment: Thanks Jorge.  I haven't been able to test as much as I'd like as a). it takes time to get a build into our test environment and b). the only practical way to test is a full server restart which also takes time, but limited tests showed even without the 1s sleep, just placing the command inside Try/Catch got it working.